# ThreadPoolExecution error with scala, slick, specs2

Tags: scala, slick, specs2

I am trying to write a db unit test for my module using slick and specs2 in scala language. I have written two tests at the moment but the second one fails with ThreadPoolExecution error. 
I have tried many approaches but still can't manage to solve my problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the test code:

```js
class UserClientSpecs extends Specification{

"App should " should {
    "add value to database" in new WithApplication {
      println("before first test")
      val recordEntry = new UserClient(None, "Lohs_atkal", 2)
      val newRecord = UserService.addUser(recordEntry)
      newRecord.onComplete {
        case Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback, meaning = $value")
        case Failure(e) => println(e.getMessage)
      }
      newRecord should not beNull
      val count = UserService.listAllUsers.map {
        v =>
          println("the number of database entries are " + v.length)
      }
    }

    "delete a record" in new WithApplication {
      println("before second test")
      val recordEntry = new UserClient(Some(0), "Lielaks Lohs", 5)
      val newRecord = UserService.addUser(recordEntry)
      newRecord.map {
        v => println("newRecord value", v)
      }
      newRecord.onComplete {
        case Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback, meaning = $value")
        case Failure(e) => println(e.getMessage)
      }
      val recordEntry2 = new UserClient(Some(1), "Lielaks Lohs2", 50)
      val newRecord2 = UserService.addUser(recordEntry2)
      val countOne = UserService.listAllUsers.map {
        res =>
          println(res.length)
      }
      val deleteUser = UserService.deleteUser(1)
      val countTwo = UserService.listAllUsers.map {
        res =>
          res should_==(1)
          res should !==(2)
      }
    }


  }
}
```

And the error I am getting when running my test through sbt -> testOnly:

```html
[play-scala] $ testOnly models.UserClientSpecs

[info] UserClientSpecs
[info] 
before first test
Got the callback, meaning = Some(UserClient(None,Lohs_atkal,2))
the number of database entries are 1
[info] App should  should
[info]   + add value to database
before second test
Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@6d01394 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7fa5be9b[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
[info]   + delete a record
[info] 
[info] Total for specification UserClientSpecs
[info] Finished in 2 seconds, 739 ms
[info] 2 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] 
[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 2
[success] Total time: 8 s, completed Mar 10, 2016 1:40:10 PM
```

Comment: Maybe you need to run your tests as `sequential` (https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.7.2/org.specs2.guide.ArgumentsReference.html#execution)?

Comment: I have tried that already. It seems like after the first test which succeeds it is not able to open the database connection again for the second test. I could put them in one connection but that wouldn't isolate the tests which makes them less reliable.